# mistake results when using SDP for large-scale matrix

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Recently I am struggling with a question during my research.

Using the following Wolfram Mathematica code I could create any even-order symmetric matrix (matriceNew in mathematica) whose entries is linear combination of many unknown parameters.

```
order = 8;
HermiteM[x_, n_] := Expand[2^(-n/2)*HermiteH[n, x/Sqrt[2]]];
GCPolynomial[x_, n_] := 1 + Sum[Subscript[\[Gamma], k]/k!*HermiteM[x, k], {k, 3, n}];
GCPolynomial[x, order];
Coefflist = CoefficientList[GCPolynomial[x, order], x];
ParaGamma = Table[Subscript[\[Gamma], k], {k, 3, order}];
n = 0;
matrice = {};
While[n <= order/2,
  matrice = 
   Append[matrice, 
    Join[Table[Subscript[q, m, n], {m, 0, n - 1}], 
     Table[Subscript[q, n, m], {m, n, order/2}]]];
  n++
  ];
Clear[n];
matrice // MatrixForm;
Length[Coefflist];
Flamatrice = Flatten[matrice];
matriceCoeff = 
  Table[Sum[
    Select[Flamatrice, #[[2]] + #[[3]] == n &][[m]], {m, 1, 
     Length[Select[Flamatrice, #[[2]] + #[[3]] == n &]]}], {n, 0, 
    order}];
relation = {};
nn = 1;
relation = Append[relation, matriceCoeff[[nn]] -> Coefflist[[nn]]];
relation = Append[relation,
   matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]] -> 
    Coefflist[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]]];
nn = 2;
relation = 
  Append[relation, 1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]] -> 1/2*Coefflist[[nn]]];
relation = 
  Append[relation, 
   1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]] -> 
    1/2*Coefflist[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]]];

ParaLambda = {};
For[n = 3, n <= 2 + IntegerPart[((Length[Coefflist] - 1)/2 - 2)/2], 
  n++,
  
  ResParaTotal = 
   Table[
    Subscript[\[Lambda], m], {m, 1 + 2*(n - 3)*(n - 2), 
     2*(n - 3)*(n - 2) + 4*(n - 2)}];
  
  ParaLambda = Join[ParaLambda, ResParaTotal];
  
  ResPara = Take[ResParaTotal, Length[ResParaTotal]/2];
  ResPara1 = Take[ResParaTotal, -Length[ResParaTotal]/2];
  nn = 2*(n - 1) - 1;
  length = Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]];
  
  relation = 
   Append[relation, matriceCoeff[[nn]][[length]] -> 2 ResPara[[1]]];
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[m]] -> ResPara[[m]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];
   ,];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[nn]] - Sum[ResPara[[m]], {m, 1, length - 1}]];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[length]] -> 
     2 ResPara[[Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]]]]];
  
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[m]] -> 
        ResPara[[m + Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];,];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]] - 
      Sum[ResPara[[m]], {m, length, Length[ResPara]}]];
  nn = 2*(n - 1);
  length = Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[length]] -> ResPara1[[1]]];
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[m]] -> ResPara1[[m]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];
   ,];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[nn]] - Sum[ResPara1[[m]], {m, 1, length - 1}]];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[length]] -> 
     ResPara1[[Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]]]]];
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[m]] -> 
        ResPara1[[m + Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];,];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]] - 
      Sum[ResPara1[[m]], {m, length, Length[ResPara1]}]];];

If[OddQ[order/2],
  ResParaTotal = 
   Table[
    Subscript[\[Lambda], m], {m, 1 + 2*(n - 3)*(n - 2), 
     2*(n - 3)*(n - 2) + 4*(n - 2)}];
  
  ResPara = Take[ResParaTotal, Length[ResParaTotal]/2];
  ResPara1 = 
   Take[ResParaTotal, {Length[ResParaTotal]/2 + 1, (
     3*Length[ResParaTotal])/4}];
  
  ParaLambda = Join[ParaLambda, ResPara];
  
  ParaLambda = Join[ParaLambda, ResPara1];
  
  nn = 2*(n - 1) - 1;
  length = Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]];
  
  relation = 
   Append[relation, matriceCoeff[[nn]][[length]] -> 2 ResPara[[1]]];
  
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[m]] -> ResPara[[m]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];
   ,];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[nn]] - Sum[ResPara[[m]], {m, 1, length - 1}]];
  
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[length]] -> 
     2 ResPara[[Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]]]]];
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[m]] -> 
        ResPara[[m + Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];
   ,];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[Length[Coefflist] - nn + 1]] - 
      Sum[ResPara[[m]], {m, length, Length[ResPara]}]];
  nn = 2*(n - 1);
  length = Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]];
  
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[length]] -> ResPara1[[1]]];
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[m]] -> ResPara1[[m]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];
   ,];
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[nn]] - Sum[ResPara1[[m]], {m, 1, length - 1}]];
  ,
  nn = 2*(n - 1) - 1;
  ResParaTotal = 
   Table[
    Subscript[\[Lambda], m], {m, 1 + 2*(n - 3)*(n - 2), 
     2*(n - 3)*(n - 2) + 4*(n - 2)}];
  
  ResPara = Take[ResParaTotal, Length[ResParaTotal]/4];
  
  ParaLambda = Join[ParaLambda, ResPara];
  
  nn = 2*(n - 1) - 1;
  length = Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]];
  
  relation = 
   Append[relation, matriceCoeff[[nn]][[length]] -> 2 ResPara[[1]]];
  
  If[length >= 3,
   relation = 
     Join[relation, 
      Table[
       1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[m]] -> ResPara[[m]], {m, 2, 
        Length[matriceCoeff[[nn]]] - 1}]];
   ,];
  
  relation = 
   Append[relation, 
    1/2*matriceCoeff[[nn]][[1]] -> 
     1/2*Coefflist[[nn]] - Sum[ResPara[[m]], {m, 1, length - 1}]];
   ];
Clear[n];
matriceNew = matrice /. relation // Expand;
matriceNew // MatrixForm
```

All I need to do is to minimize one of unknown parameters while keeping the even-order matrix semidefinite (non-negative).

When the order of matrix is below 14, I could use MOSEK, CSDP, DSDP to solve.

```
order=14; (*for example*)

res = SemidefiniteOptimization[Subscript[\[Gamma], 3], 
  VectorGreaterEqual[{Activate[Subscript[matrice, 0] \!\(\*
TagBox["+",
"InactiveToken",
BaseStyle->"Inactive",
SyntaxForm->"+"]\) 
      Join[ParaLambda, ParaGamma] . 
       Join[
        Table[
         Subscript[matriceLambda, k], {k, 1, Length[ParaLambda]}], 
        Table[
         Subscript[matriceGamma, k], {k, 3, Length[ParaGamma] + 2}]], 
     Unevaluated[Plus]], 0}, {"SemidefiniteCone", (
    Length[Coefflist] + 1)/2}], Join[ParaLambda, ParaGamma], 
  Method -> {"MOSEK", Tolerance -> 10^-9}]; (*Here, the method you could use DSDP if you might not have licence*)
Subscript[\[Gamma], 3] /. res

(* Output: Subscript[\[Gamma], 3] -> -3.30754 *)
```

which means that the minimum value of Subscript[[Gamma], 3] could be -3.30754 while keeping the 14-order matrix nonnegative.

However if the order of matrix is beyond 14, the MOSEK method is invaild.

When the order of matrix is beyond 16, the CSDP and DSDP method are invaild.

I heard one of my friend in Peking University that Gurobi is best solver in optimization. But Gurobi doesnot provide the SDP algorithms....

Could you give me a hint, how can I solve such larger-scale matrix by using SDP? when order is over 18, 20.....

Thank you very much! Your help will be in Acknowledgemwnt section in my paper~~

Comment: When you say "the XXX method is invalid", what do you mean by invalid? Is it theoretically impossible to apply? Or do you get an error? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry. Here the method is invaild means that the optimal value is \infty or the martrix is not positive under the optimal values given by this method.